# For every matrix, is column rank always equal to row rank?

Tags: linear-algebra

Take the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 1&2&3\\ 4&5&6\\2&4&6\end{pmatrix}$. Here there are two linearly independent rows, but three linearly independent columns. Isn't this a contradiction?

Comment: $2*(2,5,4)-(1,4,2)=(3,6,6)$

Answer (score 2):

This is not a contradiction since the columns aren't in fact linearly independent. Note that $c_1+c_3=2c_2$.